# WinToUsb linux version

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, ubuntu-minimal

So guys i want to install ubuntu. I have a laptop running windows 10 and i have aan empty external HDD that i want to install ubuntu to. i tried using ubuntu 18.04 LTS and minimal ubuntu 18.04 LTS but both failed. Normal one didn't even open installer for ubuntu, minimal one failed installing (couldn't download some necessary files). I am currently looking for a program like WinToUsb that can install ubuntu to my HDD from Windows and i can boot up normally. BTW i did some research and there are some programs like LiLi that you can use linux but i want to use the full linux. Is there a solution to my problems.

**EDIT:** The problem was caused by the .iso file. i re-downloaded it and installed it from my rooted phone using DriveDroid and it worked on second attempt. On first attempt ubuntu's file downloading didn't finish so i restarted the setup and didnt coonect to the internet and it installed normally. And the updates where made after installation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) From your description, seems like either the .iso was incomplete or corrupt, or you mis-made the installer by taking shortcuts or using the wrong application, or ejecting too early. Or perhaps your hardware is unusual and incompatible, though that is very rare.

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify the downloaded installation ISO file by comparing checksums? Suggest you acquire a [Windows](https://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533)  or [Linux](https://itsfoss.com/checksum-tools-guide-linux)  checksum app and verify what you downloaded was not corrupted in transit following these steps from [Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0)

Once you have verified the checksum of the ISO file downloaded matches the checksum value posted, then [make a Xubuntu](http://lifewire.com/create-lightweight-xubuntu-linux-usb-2202083) or [Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0) LiveUSB installer and you will have the equivalent of WinToUSB.

Comment: OK. will try that